# mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: mysql, row, fetch

What wrong with that?:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM biblia_forditasok 
WHERE id=$_SESSION[bible]"));
```

Here is a little more of my code:

```
       if((isset($_POST['online-bible-read-btn']) || $_GET['type'] == 'simple') && !isset($_POST['bible_search']))
       {
            if(isset($_POST['bible'])) $_SESSION['bible'] = $_POST['bible'];

            $info = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM biblia_forditasok WHERE id=$_SESSION[bible]"));

            if(isset($_POST['chapter_select'])) 
                $_SESSION['chapter'] = $_POST['chapter_select'];
            if($_SESSION['chapter'] == 0) $_SESSION['chapter'] = 1;

            $_SESSION['type'] = 'simple';
```

Comment: First can you show your mysql connect code

Comment: Please don't use MySQL.  Use MySQLi because MySQL is depreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep MySQL...

Comment: I need the code that looks like `$con = mysql_connect('server', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');`

Comment: No you can use MySQL as a database but you should be using `mysqli_connect` and `mysqli_query` instead.

Comment: What kind of variable is `$_SESSION`, is it an `int` or `string`

Comment: I will not give my passwprd and username, I'm not silly...

Comment: You shouldn't pass variables into your sql query without striping slashes by using `mysqli_escape_string`.  Your code is vulnerable to injection.

Comment: First off you can easily put in generic terms like username and password instead of giving them to me.

Comment: You should have quotes around bible and that whole value.  Also I believe id is a reserved term so you need to note that in your statement.  Try this: `$info = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM biblia_forditasok WHERE \`id\`='$_SESSION[\'bible\']'"));`

Comment: I will try this and I'll get back to you.

Comment: This is wrong, blank page...

Comment: I would check for mysql errors but also make sure that every session's name is enclosed with quotes so: `$_SESSION['bible']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     if(isset($_POST['bible'])){
     $_POST['bible'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bible']) ;
      $_SESSION['bible'] = $_POST['bible']; 
                               }

     $info = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM biblia_forditasok 
            WHERE id='".$_POST['bible']."' "));
```

Comment: I will try this and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this message because there is an error in your query. When the query is wrong `mysql_query` returns FALSE (boolean). Only if the query is correct it will return a resource.

Try using `mysql_error()` to find out what the problem is. But please don't use MySQL but MySQLi or PDO.